# Xero API - Requesting Offline_access scope

Tags: .net, xero-api, scopes

I'm trying to create a Xero token and refresh token for offline access. The URL I am creating looks like this:

```
    Dim URL As String = "https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize"
    URL += "?response_type=code"
    URL += "&client_id=" & Company.XeroClientID
    URL += "&redirect_uri=" & Server.UrlEncode(SiteBaseURL & "/Xero/" & Company.ID & "/LoginResult")
    URL += "&scope=" & Scope
    URL += "&state=" & Session("XeroState")
```

If I pass in a scope of "openid profile email accounting.transactions offline_access" then I successfully get an access token, though the scope returned only contains "openid" and there is no refresh token.

```
 {
 id_token: "...",
 access_token: "...",
 expires_in: 1800,
 token_type: "Bearer",
 scope: "openid"
 }
```

If I delimit the scopes (using Server.URLEncode) then I get an invalid scope.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Second to last should be `accounting.transactions` with an "s" on the end, or is that just a typo on here?

Comment: Thanks @dropsnoot - I have corrected it, but I am still not getting a refresh token. What should the grant_type be when using the code that is returned? I am using 'authorization_code'. If I use 'refresh_token' then I get a bad request response.

Comment: @droopsnoot - Turns out you were right - it was 2 typos in the scopes, and they had to be encoded (spaces replaced with +) to specify more than one scope. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Excellent, glad it's working for you.